# Error in Angular 4 Prod build with unexpected tokens

Tags: angular, ecmascript-5, uglifyjs, fusioncharts

I get an error when angular prod build, and I have Modified tsconfig.json to  "target": "es5", but still gets the same error as below. This came after the local installation of fusionchart packages. Please help

[image]

Comment: are you using Angular-CLI??

Comment: yes. ng serve is working without any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the ECMAScript mismatch of the FusionChart package and the Current Project.
My project is using es6 and Fusion chart required es5. You cannot have packages with different ECMAScript Versions !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this happening because you are not passing the FusionCharts library files under the fcroot module, alos I would suggest you to kindly update the fusioncharts angular plugin to the latest one which is angular-fusioncharts, for reference here is a snippet how you need to import the files and pass them under fc root module in order to do production build

```
// Import angular-fusioncharts
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';

// Import FusionCharts library and chart modules
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';

// Pass the fusioncharts library and chart modules
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionTheme);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Specify FusionChartsModule as import
    FusionChartsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

If you are still facing any problem I can share a sample for reference.